# Better Memory (Heap) management on Solaris 10

Tags: c, oracle, memory, memory-management, solaris

I have c code with embedded SQL for Oracle through Pro*C.

Whenever I do an insert or update (below given an update example),

```
update TBL1 set COL1 = :v, . . . where rowid = :v
```

To manage bulk insertions and updates, I have allocated several memory chunks to insert as bulk and commit once. There are other memory allocations too going on as and when necessary. How do I better manage the memory (heap) for dynamic memory allocations? One option is to have the heap size configurable during  the GNU linking time. I'm using g++ version 2.95, I know it's quite an old version, but have to use this for legacy. Since the executable (runs on solaris 10), obce built, could run on several production environments with varied resources, one-size-fit-all for heap size allocation may not be appropriate. As an alternative, need some mechanism where heaps may elastically grow as and when needed. Unlike Linux, Solaris, I think, does not have the concept of over-allocated memory. So, memory allocations could fail with ENOMEM if there is no more space left. What could be better strategy to know that we could be crossing the danger level and now we should either deallocate chunks that we are storing in case these are done using or transfer memory chunks to oracle DB in case these are still pending to be loaded and finally deallocate. Any strategy that you could suggest?

Comment: This is no discussion site. If you have a **specific** question with your code, post a [mcve]. And choose one language. there is no language C/C++; these are two different languages.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, edited my qs

Comment: You can always build your own memory allocator - it may not be the simplest solution, but it's the most customizable.  IBM has a decent tutorial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-memorymanager/) if you're interested.

Comment: I presume gcc, as you wrote you have C-code. `g++` normally is the name to compiler C++ code. A better idea would be use a more recent compiler. This might give more boost that hand-crafting a memory allocator. Normally the heap **does** grown dynamically. Not sure what you think to enhance. Did you even have a look at the current allocator's operation? Still, I don't think the question is OT.

Comment: @Olaf I have to use 2.95.3 version for now for legacy production code and also g++ is being  used as we have several C++ classes as well in the whole software with some C to manage the Pro*C part for embedded SQL with Oracle

Comment: Have you examined the actual memory use of your process?

Answer (score 1):

`C` is not `java` where the heap size is fixed at startup.

The heap and the stack of a `C` compiled application both share the same virtual memory space and adjust dynamically.

The size of this space depends on whether you are compiling a 32 bit or a 64 bit binary, and also whether your kernel is a 32 bit or a 64 bit one (on SPARC hardware, it's always 64 bit).

If you have not enough RAM and want Solaris to accept large memory reservations anyway, a similar way Linux over commits memory, you can just add enough swap for the reservation to be backed by actual storage.

If for some reason, you are unhappy with the Solaris libc memory allocator, you can evaluate the bundled alternative ones like [`libumem`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5168/umem-alloc-3malloc.html#scrolltoc), [`mtmalloc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5168/mtmalloc-3malloc.html) or the third party [`hoard`](http://www.hoard.org/). See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mem-alloc-1557798.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to employ soft limits in your code for various purposes, f.e. that only 100 transactions at a time are handled and other transactions have to wait until the previous ones are deallocated. This guarantees predictable behavior, as no code part can use up more memory than allowed.

The question is:
Do you really run out of memory in your application or do you fragment your memory and fail to get a sufficient large contiguous block of memory? The strategies to handle each case are different.